# Attempt to access private member in dynamic_bitset

Tags: boost

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to build LucenePlusPlus which in turn uses boost/dynamic_bitset.

The following code in LucenePlusPlus

```
const uint64_t* BitSet::getBits() {
    return bitSet.empty() ? NULL : static_cast<const uint64_t*>(&bitSet.m_bits[0]);
}
```

generates the following fatal compiler error:

```
1>g:\luceneplusplus\src\core\util\bitset.cpp(20): error C2248: 'boost::dynamic_bitset<uint64_t,std::allocator<Block>>::m_bits': cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::dynamic_bitset<uint64_t,std::allocator<Block>>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Block=uint64_t
1>        ]
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a mismatch between the version of boost and that of LucenePlusPlus. Did you check that you're using the supported/required version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have traced the code for my boost 1_75_0 and I see it has a define to conditionally reserve access to friends:

```
#if defined(BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS)
#define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_PRIVATE public
#else
#define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_PRIVATE private
#endif
```

So it looks like you should be able to add `-DBOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS` to the compiler defines to fix this.

> In fact, my LucenePlusPlus tree already contains it in
> include/config_h/Config.h.in line 107:
>
> ```
>  #define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS
> ```
>
> Previously ("rebuilt cmake buildsystem") this apparently
> came from include/Config.h.cmake, where it was always present, unconditionally all the way since 2010:
> [image]

### What Can You Do?

Maybe you are not including the required headers that include the config? Also check any interfering precompiled header settings.

If you have `boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp` included BEFORE including LucenePlusPlus headers at any point you will run with the wrong config.

> This is especially bad if you don't detect it because that would [violate the ODR rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: Added some "what can you do" information to guess what is likely going on